# date to timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in javascript to convert some date in timestamp ?

i have date in this format `2010-03-09 12:21:00` and i want to convert it into its equivalent time stamp with javascript.

Comment: Can be you be more clear on your requirement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In response to your edit:

You need to parse the *date string* to build a `Date` object, and then you can get the timestamp, for example:

```
function getTimestamp(str) {
  var d = str.match(/\d+/g); // extract date parts
  return +new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]); // build Date object
}

getTimestamp("2010-03-09 12:21:00"); // 1268158860000
```

In the above function I use a simple regular expression to extract the digits, then I build a new Date object using the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) with that parts (*Note:* The Date object handles months as 0 based numbers, e.g. 0-Jan, 1-Feb, ..., 11-Dec).

Then I use the unary plus operator to get the timestamp.

Note also that the timestamp is expressed in milliseconds.

Comment: You're right, looks like IE only understand Month as string not number, +1

Comment: i think we need to add d[2]+1 also and also need to paresInt for each mathematical operation

Answer (score 9):

```
+(new Date())
```

Does the job.

Comment: Wow thanks, that made my day ! No known compatibility issues ?

Answer (score 4):

The `getTime()` method of `Date` object instances returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch; that's a pretty good timestamp.

Comment: it will return timestamp for today. But i need to get timestamp for some random date

Comment: @AshishRajan, that's not true.  `getTime` is an *instance method* of the Date object.  That is, it works on the object itself, not the class.  You can call it on any Date you've created: `new Date("12/21/2012").getTime()` does ***not*** equal `new Date().getTime()`
======
I get that this is an old post, but it *should* help people hitting this page in the future