# Javascript Datestring Converter with Timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime

Using JavaScript, how do I translate date strings like these:

```
Sep 13, 1:13PM GMT+01:00
Sep 12, 4:00PM EDT
```

to either a Unix timestamp or JavaScript milliseconds since the epoch?

I think the format is:

```
MMM DD, h:mmtt ?K
```

Comment: Being that that is not a valid date string, you will have to parse it with regex and build the date yourself

Comment: Regex should be able to change the string to do something like this new Date('13 Sep, 2012 01:13').getTime() but that doesn't incorporate the timezone information?

Comment: @JamesKleeh is right, here's an example to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407052/date-to-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: Can anyone help finish the answer below? Maybe @james-kleeh ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this far which is close to the answer.

- It does a regex over the string and captures each element in to a group
- The 24h representation of the time is corrected
- I've assumed that it is the current year
- It fails to take in to account the timezone
- Using the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method

```js
function getTimestamp(str){
 var re = /(\w{3}) (\d{2}), (\d):(\d{2})(\w{2}) (.*)/;
  var match = re.exec(str);
  if (match !== null) {
      var HH = match[5]==='PM' ? +match[3]+12 : match[3];
      return Date.parse(match[1]+' '+match[2]+', '+new Date().getFullYear()+' '+ HH +':'+match[4]);
  }
}

getTimestamp('Sep 12, 4:00PM EDT'); //=> 1347462000000
```