# Countdown timer - How to avoid resetting of timer

Tags: javascript

I have to add a countdown timer in my online testing website, but everytime I click on the next or any other button, the timer resets. What should I do to avoid that? Here is the code I used

```
   <span id="countdown-1">10 seconds</span>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // Initialize clock countdowns by using the total seconds in the elements tag
   secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-1').innerHTML,10);
   setTimeout("countdown('countdown-1',"+secs+")", 1000);
   secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-2').innerHTML,10);
   setTimeout("countdown('countdown-2',"+secs+")", 1000);

    function countdown(id, timer){
    timer--;
    minRemain  = Math.floor(timer / 60);
    secsRemain = new String(timer - (minRemain * 60));
    // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
    if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
        secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
    }

    // String format the remaining time
    clock      = minRemain + ":" + secsRemain;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
    if ( timer > 0 ) {
        // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
        setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);
    } else {
        // Time is out! Hide the countdown

     alert('time finished');
     return false;
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhh, you do realize that JavaScript is not PHP, right?

Comment: You could use a database, global variables, or even writing to a document. Store the time when the next page is accessed, and load that time when the page is loaded. Also you might want to add the JavaScript tag ;)

Comment: yes, but this is the part of js code I have embedded in my php file to make the countdown run

Comment: I am completely new with this....could anyone please help with the coding..?

Comment: Wow, give people some time to check it out first.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know to what date you are counting down to.

```
<?php
$dueTime = mktime(0,0,0, 1, 1, 2015);
$secondsRemaining = $dueTIme - time();
?>

<span id="countdown-1"><?php echo $secondsRemaining; ?> seconds</span>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       // Initialize clock countdowns by using the total seconds in the elements tag
       secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-1').innerHTML,10);
       setTimeout("countdown('countdown-1',"+secs+")", 1000);
       secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-2').innerHTML,10);
       setTimeout("countdown('countdown-2',"+secs+")", 1000);

        function countdown(id, timer){
        timer--;
        minRemain  = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        secsRemain = new String(timer - (minRemain * 60));
        // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
        if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
            secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
        }

        // String format the remaining time
        clock      = minRemain + ":" + secsRemain;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
        if ( timer > 0 ) {
            // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
            setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);
        } else {
            // Time is out! Hide the countdown

         alert('time finished');
         return false;
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just need a normal timer for a test after which the testing page is redirected to another one....don't really know how to do that...this is the one I tried and it didn't work for the whole test

Comment: no its not working....I mean the timer is getting reset and that is really irritating

Comment: Are you sure there is any php involved in what you are doing?

Comment: the whole thing is in php only...for your code, only number of seconds are visible....rest everything written after that part is gone

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to check the answer to close the question. That makes uspporters happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript is client side, it will refresh the countdown each time you refresh the page.

You have to make a countdown to a given `timestamp`.
Thanks to that, you will be able to keep the count correct.

Somthing like this : (function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407052/date-to-timestamp-in-javascript))

```
function getTimestamp(str) {
  var d = str.match(/\d+/g); // extract date parts
  return +new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]); // build Date object
}

var countdown = getTimestamp("2012-05-12 18:00:00") - (+new Date);
```

Because timestamp is a fix point in the future!